# where are the coordinates of an area map in HTML measured from?

Tags: javascript, html, image

for an area inside an image there is left, top, right, bottom, I am confused and I have few questions about this, in this case I will use a rect example.

1- where are they measured from, is it from the image or from the page?

2- do they define position or dimensions? I am confused because position required only 2 coordinates for a 2D page.

here is the code I tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>How to define an area inside an image-map
</title>
</head>
<body>  

 <!--alt= "area example" is the text to be displayed if the pic cannot be shown -->
 <!--usemap = "" mean that we want this image to have different clickable area that links to other pages, #Map is a reference to the map name that we want to use. -->

 <!-- width and height do not define position, but rather define dimensions, position is later defined CSS-->
<img src="http://www.w3resource.com/html/area/html-area-element.png" alt="area example " width="308" height="270" border="10" usemap="#Map"> 


 <!-- coords define size and position by using coordinates, so you pick how far you want your area -->
 <!-- for rect coords works like left,top,right,bottom  -->
 <!-- for circ coords works like x circle center from left, y circle center from top , radius of circle -->
<map name="Map">  
<area shape="rect" coords="8,5,100,180" href="http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-tutorials.php" target="_blank" alt="mysql tutorial">  
<area shape="circle" coords="155,150,59" href="http://www.w3resource.com/php/php-home.php" target="_blank" alt="php tutorial">  
<area shape="rect" coords="197,136,306,188" href="http://www.w3resource.com/sql/sql-tutorials.php" alt="sql tutorials">  
</map>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sure you could figure this out by executing a few tests with javascript?

Comment: _"is it from the image or from the image?"_ erm, whut?

Comment: I meant from the whole page

Comment: @bwright I know the assumption on SF is always that the OP is a programmer, but I'm actually an absolute beginner

Comment: @MohamedHegazy Don't worry about it, everybody starts somewhere. Could you provide any code so we can help you figure it out? Because I think everybody is a little bit confused where you're coming from. Are you talking about the positioning of an element on a page ? Also is javasript related to this? Or is this a CSS question?

Comment: @5parc thanks alot, It's actually a HTML question, I was doing a map of hyperlinks of specified area and position within an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have ran some tests to get it, but anyways it is like this :

[image]

## **EDIT:**

Saw your second question after answering so here is answer for it:
Coords looks something like this `coords="8,5,100,180"`
which stands for `x1,y1,x2,y2` where `(x1,y1)` are the coords of one corner of rectangle and `(x2,y2)` are coords of opposite corner.